# Is there a way to configure "waitTime"/Hold for messages in Spring-cloud-stream apps using Kafka, before sending to downstream apps?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have 2 Spring Cloud stream Applications "Scs-Processor" and "SCS-Sink" and I am using Kafka to send messages

Here's my use case:-

1) I have a **message1** with payload attribute "**payloadIdentifier**" -->> **Ktopic1**--->>received by **SCS-Processor**

2) Now message2 comes in -->> This **message2** has **different** Payload but **same** "**payloadIdentifier**" --->> received by SCS-Processor

Now I want to send "**messageNew**" which is essentially a **merger** of **message1** and **message2** with same **payloadidentifier** to "**SCS-Sink**"

Is there way we can check the incoming message and hold either in Kafka/SCS to achieve this ?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is an EIP [Aggregation](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) pattern where `payloadIdentifier ` is a _correlation id_. It is really a complex use case as it comes with tons of caveats you need to think about. . . For example, what if second message never arrives? What if it arrives but late, etc? Given that spring-cloud-stream builds on spring-integration, consider looking into [aggregator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#overview-endpoints-aggregator)

Comment: Thank you Oleg, I have been trying to understand this "Aggregator" functionality. I am unable to understand how do I implement a "CustomCorelationStrategy" which basically indicates to look for messages with "payloadId" and then Aggregate "payloadValue" into a list and then a "ReleaseStrategy" based on condition that "size ==2". If you could help me in understanding this better. Thank you. I am very new to Spring Integration and this is a very useful functionality.

Comment: Is there a basic example I could use to see how I can implement a custom strategy for Aggregator ? I only ask you this because there's no examples that I could find online which can help me understand this better. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, here are some samples for you to read up. [Splitter-aggregator-reaper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/splitter-aggregator-reaper). You may skip the splitter part, but aggregator/reaper is relevant to your case especially the reaper as it handles those edge cases when expectations aren't met. Also, if you look for the word `aggregator` in SI [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) you'll find more. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you Oleg. But I have been trying to understand this from a Spring Cloud Stream perspective. Just want to know how I can use the options or code the Custom Strategies for the SCSProcessor App above.

Comment: With current binder implementation you can look at Spring Cloud Stream(SCSt) as just a connectivity wrapper over Spring Integration(SI); That is: Binders bind target destinations (e.g., topics, queues) to SI channels. Once the message is in the SI channel it's all spring-integration from there on, hence the importance of the reference material I provided. Here is some additional examples of [existing SCSt apps](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=aggregat&type=&language=) for you reference.